# Can I toggle floated modules without affecting all modules below?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slidetoggle

Four modules that have hidden content activated by a click function. Just click on the image or lorem paragraph and you'll see the hidden content.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gvcxd

Ultimately, this is for a responsive design. So, the amount of columns will change depending on the viewport size and how wide each module is from a media query definition.

I'd like to modify this script so that the modules on the other column doesn't move. In other words, when you click on "ONE", then the only module that moves is "THREE" since it is below. "TWO" and "FOUR" should stay static.

Here's how it looks simplistically:

```
1 2         ( <---This is a faux-row, since it's not coded to be a row)
3 4
```

When I click on the toggle for 2, it looks like this (H for hidden content):

```
1 2
  H
3 4
```

3 has been pushed down and this shouldn't happen. Instead, I want it to be just this:

```
1 2
3 H
  4
```

Is it possible to have this toggle script functionality so that the click function only affects the faux-column below it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using z-index as you basically just want the article to slide down on top of the elements below it.

Using the basic pattern you laid out above, I put together a brief example of this. You'll have to adapt it a bit to exactly what you're doing, but it demonstrated the concept.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one" class="main-block">ONE
        <div class="article">blah blah blah</div>
    </div>
    <div id="two" class="main-block">TWO
        <div class="article">blah blah blah</div>
    </div>
    <div id="three" class="main-block">THREE
        <div class="article">blah blah blah</div>
    </div>
    <div id="four" class="main-block">FOUR
        <div class="article">blah blah blah</div>
    </div>
    <div id="five" class="main-block">FIVE
        <div class="article">blah blah blah</div>
    </div>
    <div id="six" class="main-block">SIX
        <div class="article">blah blah blah</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main-block {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 50px;
    width: 75px;
}
.article {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;  
    width: 150px;    
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.article').hide();

$('.main-block').click(function() {
    $(this).children('.article').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

You can also play with it on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f42hj/)

Comment: Oh wow, interesting. I'll have to give it a try and see if the clients like it. The only problem is the divs that are under the dropped content shows through, such as box shadows, borders and edges. Since it's a responsive site, I can't just tell specific divs to disappear temporarily. But its' a challenge I'll have to figure out. Thanks for an interesting solution!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can toggle `visiblity: hidden` rather than using `display: none` so the element will still be in the DOM, etc. but will be completely transparent:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/visibility

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but keeping the hidden content in the DOM doesn't fix the root of the problem that it's pushing down the modules below the one which is active.

Comment: Yeah, it would allow you to make your elements constant but you could potentially have a significant amount of extra space depending on the relative sizes of the always-visible and hidden components, which might not be amenable to something like a z-index approach.

Comment: If you're really set on columnar behaviour, perhaps you want to use the CSS3 columns module and investigate the IE<10 polyfill situation for

Comment: If I use visibility:hidden, I would still need to visibly hide the hidden content so that they toggle out. Also, the amount of content will vary from module to module. Trying to have columns isn't the problem and it will change depending on the viewport because it's a responsive design. It's the behavior of modules after one is activated by a click function. Were you able to see what I'm talking about in the codepen link? I updated the above description because "1" works differently than the rest.